# Angular 6: How to install a previous version of Angular project

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-cli-v6

How I can install a previous version of Angular project with the current Angular-cli version (Angular 6).

I found a command but is deprecated:

`ng new my_project --ng4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to use angular-cli to create new project, you need to install the version of `@angular/cli` that scaffolds angular 4 project.

Version of `@angular/cli` which scaffolds the Angular 4 project is `1.4.9`.

So, using npm, do `npm install @angular/cli@1.4.9`, then use `angular-cli` commands.

Comment: But I don't want to remove my current Angular cli version, is just for one project, my others project use the current angular cli version

Comment: @Ricky, You don't have to remove the current Angular cli version. You can install one version of Angular cli for each folder.  

There are two ways to install things using NPM:

globally —- This drops modules in {prefix}/lib/node_modules, and puts executable files in {prefix}/bin, where {prefix} is usually something like /usr/local. It also installs man pages in {prefix}/share/man, if they’re supplied.
locally —- This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in ./node_modules, executables go in ./node_modules/.bin/, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

Comment: @Ricky , as long as you install the npm package locally with out using `-g` flag, you are fine. If you install a package with specific version on a directory, only that directory will have the package with the version you have just installed.For reference -> [https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)

Comment: Oh It's very helpful your answer and I din't know that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a aditional question: Where I can find what version of angular cli is for Angular 5?

Comment: For that you need to look through `@angular/cli` releases. Goto [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), there you can check releases. Then you have to identify the release which scaffolds which version of angular. e.g.  `@angular/cli` version `1.7.x` is for `Angular 5`, etc

Comment: I was installed `npm install @angular/cli@1.7.3` version of Angular Cli. This create a node_modules folder, in my current directory (where I was installed Angular-cli@1.7.3), but when I run `ng new myap` Angular 6 is installed and I need Angular 5.

Comment: I think that when I run `ng new myapp`, is taking the global ng, how do I take the version that I installed in my current directory?

Comment: @Ricky, Make sure you have not installed `@angular/cli` with version greater than `1.7.3`, You can check the version with command `ng -v`. I have tested this, and I can confirm that if you install version `1.7.3` locally, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just have `package.json` with specific version and do `npm install` and it will install that version. Also you dont need to depend on **angular-cli** to develop your project.

Other thing is you can remove the latest version of angular-cli and install minor version of it. Then create the project.

Let me explain:

[STEP 0 - OPTIONAL] If you're not sure of the angular-cli version installed in your environment, uninstall it.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then, run

```
npm cache clean
```

or, if you're using npm > 5

```
npm cache verify
```

[STEP 1] Install an angular-cli specific version

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@wished.version.here
```

[STEP 2] Create a project

```
ng new you-app-name
```

The resulting white app will be created in the **desired angular version**.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but i don't need to uninstall my  current angular cli version. I need just to install an Angular 5 project for one project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better answer for me. I share it with you:

**How to install Angular 2:**

npm install @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.33.1
This install the 2.4.0 version

**How to install Angular 4:**

npm install @angular/cli@1.4
This install the 4.2.4 version

**How to install Angular 5:**

npm install @angular/cli@1
This install @angular/cli@1.5

All this installations it must be installed **as local** projects dependencies

I hope you find it useful.