# How to Create a specific version of Angular Project using CLI?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

My **npm version is 5.5.1** and **angular cli version is 6.2.1**. When I try to create a new project using the command `ng new Project_name` then it is creating the latest version of Angular (in my case **it is creating Angular version ^6.1.0**), but **I want Angular 4**.

My question is ***how do I create a new Angular 2/4/5 project using a specific version, instead of the latest version?***

I don't think changing the version value in **package.json** will help in my case because there are some differences in the older versions and the latest 6 version (like the name of one file has been changed from angular-cli.json to angular.json and not only name but content is also changed).

I've also raised the same question on [the angular-cli GitHub site](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12270).

Comment: IMHO, you must install CLI that is aligned with Angular4, was published at that time. AFAIK there is no flag to create project with older version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6: How to install a previous version of Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272621/angular-6-how-to-install-a-previous-version-of-angular-project)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Using CLI you can not create a specific angular version.

But you can install a specific version of angular CLI into a particular folder.

**For Example:**

First `create new folder` inside any drive. I'm going to create a demo folder in D drive. Ex: `d:\projects\demo`.

Then find this folder inside `Command Prompt(cmd)` or just type `cmd` into your created folder address bar in Windows and hit enter.

Now type angular specific version command: `npm install @angular/cli@1.7.x` for angular 5. and use a similar command for the other version.

After completing the installation, just create a new angular project in your specific folder that you recently installed angular. Ex: `d:\projects\demo\`.

Now create an angular project using the command `npx ng new Project_name` and it will create a `your specific angular version` Project.

In my example, it will create an angular 5 project.

Comment: Instead of creating the project inside the demo/ folder, use `ng new Project_name --directory ./` to create that project in the current directory.

Comment: This wasn't working form me. Last step fail: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I still get a "A merge conflicted on path package.json" because I don't want to have 2 different node-modules folders, My global is v12 and I'd like to install v11, what can I do?  
@SerzhanAkhmetov

Comment: Delete package.json file then run command: `node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng new Project_name --directory ./`

Answer (score 164):

You can use **npx** command which is **Node.js** package runner, by running packages directly from the registry without effecting the globally installed package registry (-g).

@next will automatically install the latest preview version from Angular repo (now days refers to version 9 rc), like so:

```
npx @angular/cli@next new Angular9Project
```

Otherwise, you can provide the specific version:

```
npx @angular/cli@7 new Angular7Project
```

> NPX comes bundled with NPM version 5.2+

Answer (score 39):

The Easy Way:
example:`npm install @angular/cli@6` 
here the -g flag tells npm to do this install globally. The 6 on the end tells npm that I want the latest available version 6.

if I want to create a new application for Angular 5 I do this :

```
> npm install @angular/cli@1
> ng new my-ng5-app
```

Remember, Angular CLI was version 1.7 for Angular 5.

if I want to create a new application for Angular 6 I do this :

```
> npm install @angular/cli@6
> ng new my-ng6-app
```

if I want to create a new application for Angular 7 I do this :

```
> npm install @angular/cli@7
> ng new my-ng7-app
```

if I want to create a new application for Angular 12 I do this :

```
> npm install @angular/cli@12
> ng new my-app-name
```

I hope it would be helpful for you thanks....!

Comment: Great answer, it helped me. But why are you installing the "cli" globally? It worked for me with "npm i @angular/cli@7", so it installs the version 7 on the folder and keeps my global cli with the version 8

Comment: Won't -g flag effect the other projects?

Comment: this answer has been edited to remove the -g flag. so it won't work because the global installation of angular-cli is used to create new projects.

the -g flag won't affect other projects because each project has a local installation of angular-cli

Comment: This didn't work for me. The angular still created angular version 16, which was installed globally using -g. What I wanted was angular version 11.

Comment: install without using the '-g' flag

Answer (score 14):

I think the easiest and flexible solution is to use npx:

```
npm install -g npx
```

for example for create a new angular 11 project:

```
npx -p @angular/cli@11.1.2 ng new Angular11App
```

Answer (score 9):

> **TL;DR**
> **Use a package called npx *(run `npm i -g npx` if not already installed)* and when you need to create an angular project, just use this command the very  first time: 
>  `npx -p @angular/cli@latest ng new hello-world-project`**
>
> ***Note***: Replace `@latest` with your desired CLI version.
> ***Remember:***,
> For Angular 6 & above, the Angular-CLI version has been brought to the same level as the Angular such that `npx -p @angular/cli@6` creates angular 6 project & `npx -p @angular/cli@7` creates angular 7 project etc.

***Explanation:*** 
So For example if you want to create angular 4 project, modify the above command to include the angular-cli version 1.4.10 like this `npx -p @angular/cli@1.4.10 ng new hello-world-project` and then when your project setup is complete you can go back to using the normal `ng generate` and other commands.

> Angular-cli versions indicate which angular version will be associated
> with a project & angular-cli 1.4.10 creates angular 4 projects

**Edits:**

**Here is some useful versioning info about which cli creates which angular version.**

```
 CLI version     Angular version

 1.0 - 1.4.x       ^4.0.0
 1.5.x             ^5.0.0
 1.6.x - 1.7.x     ^5.2.0
 6.x               ^6.0.0
 7.x               ^7.0.0
```

Also, if you want to use latest stable version to create a certain angular project you can just use npx command like this `npx -p @angular/cli@1.7` and it will use cli version 1.7.4 which is the most latest stable version for angular 5.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**this should work
Use a package called `npx npm i -g npx` and when you need to create an angular project use this command the first time `npx -p @angular/cli ng new hello-world-project`**
 after that you can use normal commands to work like `ng g c abc`

Answer (score 2):

Create a `package.json` file then define the angular version you want to install then run `npm install` it will create project in the required version irrespective of the global angular cli

Comment: this is great solution if you want to downgrade a project, in my case from 14 (not lts yet) to v13-lts , edit you existing package.json file, change all version numbers to "^13.0.0" and remember to match all dependencies version when you try to install with these commands `$rm -rf node_modules`, `$rm pacakge-lock.json`; `$npm install`

Comment: to install specific version of angular cli `$npm uninstall --location=global @angular/cli`, `$npm install --location=global @angular/cli@v13-lts` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below `npx -p @angular/cli@12.0.0 ng new angular12App`