# Angular 4 installation issue

Tags: node.js, angular

I have installed node 6.10.0 in my system, and I further want to install angular 4.
I am using the command 
    npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4
But i am unable to do so. Need some suggestions.
PS: I use windows

Comment: Could you please specify the problem? For example, what errros do you get?

Comment: "But i am unable to do so" ... why?

Comment: First install latest angular globally. than after install angular 4 in particular folder. Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331625/how-to-create-a-specific-version-of-angular-project-using-cli/52331718#52331718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install latest version from your cli. Then Specify the version you want in the 'dependencies' section of your package.json. For example if you want `Angular 4.3.4` then you can edit you package.json file like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.4",
     ...........................
     ...........................
    }
```

Also change your devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.4",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.4",
  .............
}
```

now run `npm install`

```
 npm install
```

After finishing install you should see your version by `ng -v` command like this

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.3.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.25
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.48
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.13
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

PS: From your question, you have mentioned `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4` there is no 1.4 version when you are trying to install **angular 4**