# Local Angular CLI version greater than global

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am currently trying to create a new Angular project with Angular CLI version `13.3.10`. Yet when I create a new Angular project I still get version `13.3.11`.

Before I created this project I ran `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and `npm install -g @angular/cli@13.3.10` as an administrator.

Eventhough I uninstalled (checked if it was uninstalled) and installed the desired version `ng new {project name}` still generates a project with the Angular CLI version `13.3.11`. How can that happen?

Comment: The requirements aren't pinned that tightly, ~13.3.10 includes 13.3.11 as it's just a patch change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your problem could be, installing the preferred version of angular locally inside a folder, just for this particular project.

**For Example :**

First `create a new folder` inside any drive. I'm going to create demo folder in D drive. Ex: `d:\projects\demo`.

Then find this folder inside `Command Prompt(cmd)` or just type cmd into your created folder address bar in windows and hit enter.

Now type angular specific version command : `npm install @angular/cli@13.3.10.`

notice there is no `-g` in that command, because we don't want to install that version `globally`

which also means that for every new project you have to repeat those steps

After complete the installation, just create new angular project into your specific folder that you recently install angular. Ex: d:\projects\demo.

Now create the project using the command `ng new Project_name` and it will create your specific angular version Project.

[Here is a similiar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331625/how-to-create-a-specific-version-of-angular-project-using-cli)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can customize here is the version of @angular/cli to be used (it is not documented now but exists for v13 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/13.3.x/packages/schematics/angular/ng-new/schema.json#L85)
`ng new --version 13.3.10`
**Note**: it will be with '~' before your version anyway as per template beelow

Angular versions are supposed to be the latest available as per template
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/13.3.x/packages/schematics/angular/workspace/files/package.json.template#L13

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/common": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/compiler": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/core": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/forms": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "@angular/router": "<%= latestVersions.Angular %>",
    "rxjs": "<%= latestVersions['rxjs'] %>",
    "tslib": "<%= latestVersions['tslib'] %>",
    "zone.js": "<%= latestVersions['zone.js'] %>"
  },
```